# Cómo rellenar un array que tiene elementos indefinidos?

Tags: javascript, array

He visto que lo realizar con Array.apply, pero además de este método, cual más puede hacerse? sin usar bucles

**Intento 1:**

```
 var i = new Array(100).filter((val,index)=> { 
    return index;
    });  // Devuelve []
```

**Intento 2:**

```js
var n = new Array(10).map((val,index) => {return index;})
console.log(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada rellenar con que ¿Tu arreglo? ya que si lo quieres rellenar con otro puedes ocupar lo que muestran [Aquí](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array), si lo que quieres es hacerlo por ti puedes hacer lo siguiente arreglo[index]=valor; ó tienes la opción de ocupar el método each algo similar a esto

```
$.each(arrayOne, function(index, value) {alert(index + ': ' + value); });
```

Espero que te sirva, explica mas tu propósito para poder intentar ayudarme mas.

Comment: Con jquery no por favor

Answer (score 0):

**Respuesta corta**: Utiliza la función **fill** de *Array*.

Recibe 3 parámetros: El valor con el que quieres rellenar tu array, desde qué índice comenzar y en qué índice terminar. Los índices son opcionales.

---

Cuando haces `new Array(10);` obtienes un array que contiene espacio para 10 elementos. Pero si muestras esto por ejemplo en la consola de *Chrome*, verás:

```
new Array(10);   // => (10) [empty × 10]
```

Cuando usas la función `map`, esta intenta iterar sobre todos los elementos del array, pero como son `empty`, no puede iterar porque no hay nada sobre qué iterar.

Hay que notar que `empty` **es diferente de** `undefined`. `empty` ni siquiera existe, solo se muestra para avisarte que no hay nada. Mientras que podemos rellenar un array de valores `undefined` y *mapearlo*:

```
new Array(10).map(() => 3);                   // > [empty × 10]
new Array(10).fill(undefined).map(() => 3);   // > [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
new Array(10).fill().map(() => 3);            // > [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

`fill(undefined)` y `fill()` son equivalentes. Ahora, entiendo que quieres crear un rango de valores en tu Array. Puedes mapearlo como intentabas:

```
new Array(5).fill()
            .map((valorActual, indice) => indice);        // > [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

let valorInicial = 7;
new Array(5).fill()
            .map((v, indice) => indice + valorInicial);   // > [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Y usando los otros posibles parámetros para fill, puedes crear otras cosas:

```
new Array(10).fill(undefined, 5)
             .map((v, indice) => indice);     // > [empty × 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

new Array(10).fill(undefined, 3, 7)
             .map((v, indice) => indice + 3); // > [empty × 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, empty × 3]

new Array(10).fill(undefined, 3)
             .map((v, indice) => indice * 5)
             .fill(undefined, 7);             // > [empty × 3, 15, 20, 25, 30, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```